# Mandatory key in interface based on optional generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is there a way in Typescript to make an interface have a mandatory key when a generic is passed into it?

I am looking for a way to be able to defined types for keys in interfaces only when a Generic is passed into it.

eg.

```
interface IExample {
  foo: string
}
​
/* You can't declare 2 interfaces of the same name, but this shows the structure I am aiming for */
interface IExample<T> {
  foo: string,
  bar: T
}
​
/* Allowed */
const withoutBar: IExample {
  foo: 'some string'
}
​
/* Not allowed, as I've passed in a generic for Bar */
const withoutBar: IExample<number> {
  foo: 'some string'
}
​
/* Allowed */
const withBar: IExample<number> {
  foo: 'some string',
  bar: 1
};
​
/* Not allowed as I have not passed in a generic for Bar */
const withBar: IExample {
  foo: 'some string',
  bar: 1 // Should error on "bar" as I have not passed in a generic
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could a type alias with a conditional type.

```
type IExample<T = void> = T extends void ?  {
  foo: string
} : {
  foo: string,
  bar: T
}
​​
/* Allowed */
const withoutBar: IExample = {
  foo: 'some string'
}
​
/* Not allowed, as I've passed in a generic for Bar */
const withoutBar: IExample<number> = {
  foo: 'some string'
}
​
/* Allowed */
const withBar: IExample<number> = {
  foo: 'some string',
  bar: 1
};
​
/* Not allowed as I have not passed in a generic for Bar */
const withBar: IExample = {
  foo: 'some string',
  bar: 1 // Should error on "bar" as I have not passed in a generic
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgogDwIYFswBsIB4AqUC8UAbgPYCWAJgHwFR4QLAQB2FAzseRVAPxRQBvAFD8AZiRIAuKG2AAnMswDmQgL5RpwsROmyFygDQioAIyRzpONUMDQBDaEB6AFRQAgunQkA7hG5OHQgDGJMyyUF5kwAAWJACuwABC5tLwyGiYtFpQ4lJQAORsJCjQeopKedb2zlAAciTAUEge3r4GjRwweUTQYEhsbL5Qio1QSiwQCoHZJHJQSbP+QSFhEdFxicmwiKgY2MyxKCYTNIRZOdIFRSXyZRWqto4u7p4+fgHBoQ2rUfMp2+l7A5HOQnQTGc75QrFGQ3ZR5Iz8MwWKAARjUAG4HtU6g0mi9Bn1YFAokhulBmPUoL1+oNhkhRuNJtNZvMoIsPitIj9NqkdhlTuCdJCrjD9OUEaZNiioA4HFAAMoxWLobgTOQzKAhKAAIiR2vaRJJZIpDWpA24dIZzAmZECGKAA)

Comment: Works perfectly! I need to practice with conditional types. Thanks!